# Google Cloud Vision API online vs offline pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision

I'm in need of a plug and play text recognition system after having tried some solutions such as Tesseract OCR, Google's Vision API seemed to produce the best results for me.

However I have never used any of their cloud API before but I've noticed it is able to work [offline](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch)? How would billing work for this? As I understand the online version charges for every 1000 images, wouldn't the offline library circumvent this? What is the quality difference between online and offline?

Comment: I never heard of any offline solution for OCR from google. Other vendors - such as ABBYY or NUANCE - offer such solutions. But the pricing is much higher - you should expect at least between 1 and 3 Euro-Cent per document for higher volumes (more than 50.000 documents). Smaller volumes are even more expensive. The quality of the results of ABBYY is quite similiar to google's vision API. But as far as I could see from my own tests, ABBYY does have more problems with distorted or "dirty" images than google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both online and offline charge based on the features used. Here is the pricing chart: https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing

Quality should be similar for online and offline. You could run a small experiment with your own files to verify this.

Comment: Is it possible to run offline version on a machine that cannot connect to the internet? I'm guessing there must be a way the library needs to report back usage.

Comment: Ah, by offline you are referring to on-premise. I don't think Vision API has that yet. Why can't the machine connect to the internet?

Comment: Documentation we're scanning cannot leave a specific building's basement which has no wifi signal or ethernet. The text conversion process must be done on site and scanned images erased when completed so we can't batch scan first.